# Getting the error "Wrap the parameter in parens" from JSLint, why?

Tags: javascript, jslint

After executing JSLint I'm getting the following message:

> Wrap the parameter in parens.
>
> 1 Expected '(' before 'info'. const valueArr = (info => { // Line 6,
>   Pos 19

I've read the [Lint paren rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) but still I'm not sure what the problem is and how to handle it. My code:

```
const valueArr = (info => {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        try {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            .....
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated**:

I already tried to put it with parens, but another warnings came up:

> "Expected 'function' and instead saw '=>'. const valueArr = ((info) =>
>   {".

```
const valueArr = ((info) => {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        try {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The rule is pretty clear - it requires the parameter to be wrapped in parenthesis - `(info)`.

Comment: The error tells you what to do?!

Comment: When I tried to put the parens, it got me other multiple errors like 'expected function' or 'use strict' so it's not clear for me if I'm doing it correctly. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @Emirodgar each of those rules is documented here, with examples: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This rule enforces parentheses around arrow function parameters regardless of arity.
>   ([source](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens))

That rule determines that this line:

```
const valueArr = (info => {
```

Should be changed to this:

```
const valueArr = ((info) => {
```

Because arrow function parameters must be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that but got another message: "#1 Expected 'function' and instead saw '=>'.  const valueArr = ((info) => { // Line 6, Pos 29"

Comment: That's another rule, @Emirodgar. Apparently, your JSLint is configured to disallow arrow functions.

Comment: Understood, that was the thing, I thought it was related. Thanks for your help.